# Get facebook users email

Tags: facebook, email

I am looking for a way, that when I get a Facebook user ID, I can get their email too.
At the moment, I cannot find any way to get their email from their Facebook acc/id.

Comment: Please show your code to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the email of a user is by creating an App and letting the user authorize it with the "email" permission/scope. There is no other way.